# elementary negation

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I couldn't be sure about the negation of the statement $\exists x \in N , x < 3$

is it
$$
\lnot(\exists x \in N , x < 3) \equiv (\forall x \in N , x \geq 3)
$$
or
$$
\lnot (\exists x \in N , x < 3) \equiv (\forall x \notin N , x \geq 3)
$$
can someone help me (with an explanation)?

Comment: [This might be helpful](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200325/what-is-the-negation-of-this-statement/200332#200332).

Answer (score 4):

When we write $\forall x\in A:\varphi(x)$ we actually abbreviate $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow \varphi(x))$; and when we write $\exists x\in A:\varphi(x)$ we abbreviate $\exists x(x\in A\land\varphi(x))$.

Two useful equivalences I will use are

1. $\lnot(p\land q)\iff(\lnot p\lor\lnot q)$, and
2. $p\rightarrow q\iff\lnot p\lor q$.

Now recall that $\lnot\exists x\varphi(x)$ is equivalent to $\forall x\lnot\varphi(x)$. Use both and we have:

$$\begin{align}
\lnot(\exists x\in N:x< 3)
&\iff\lnot(\exists x(x\in N\land x< 3))\\
&\iff\forall x(\lnot (x\in N\land x< 3))\\
&\iff\forall x(x\notin N\lor x\geq 3)\\
&\iff\forall x(x\in N\rightarrow x\geq 3)\\
&\iff\forall x\in N:x\geq 3
\end{align}$$

Comment: I mostly got the idea and the explanation but I have one other question, at the beginning why did you expressed ¬(∃x∈N:x<3)⟺¬(∃x(x∈N∧x<3)) using ∧ and then at the end you did ∀x(x∈N→x≥3) ⟺ (∀x∈N:x≥3). By doing so you transformed → into semicolon. Is semicolon ∧ or → ??

Comment: @Deniz: Neither. The $:$ is what you used a comma for. I just really hate commas in formal sentences.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align*}
\lnot (\exists x \in N, x < 3) &\equiv \forall x \in N, \lnot(x < 3)\\
&\equiv \forall x \in N, x \geq 3
\end{align*}
$$

---

Think about what the sentence is saying in words. The original claim is

> $N$ contains a number smaller than 3.

Imagine someone says this to you, but you're certain that person is mistaken. What would you have to show them in order to *negate* the claim? In words, you might say "You are mistaken. The truth is:

> $N$ does *not* contain a number smaller than 3.

In other words:

> Every number belonging to $N$ is greater than or equal to 3.

You would most certainly not want to start talking about numbers not belonging to $N$. The person you wish to refute made no claim about such numbers, so neither should your refutation involve them.

Answer (score 1):

just to be sure, to me your statement reads as "There exists an $x$, element of the positive integers (doesn't matter with or withour $0$), such that $x$ is less than $3$. If this is correct, then the negation is: There is no $x$ element of the positive integers such that $x$ is less than $3$. This means that all $x$ element of the positive integers are greater equal $3$.